# What is the best way for me to re-learn D&D rules to be a DM and introduce game to kids?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-gm, system-introduction, kids

My daughter, who is about 12, recently was given the Starter Set for D&D.  She has never played before and would like me to DM for her and either her friends, her sister, whomever (assume none have ever played). While I played a decent amount 25-30 years ago in my teens, I can't say I remember any actual rules and the 30-page instruction manual that comes with the starter set is pretty dense with rules.  What is the best way for me to re-learn the rules so that I can best introduce her to the game and give her the best experience so she wants to keep playing?  It is the 5th edition starter set and comes with an adventure book for Lost Mine of Phandelver.

I have read the rule book, but not the adventure yet.  But it is way beyond figuring out the "new" rules.  You should assume I remember almost nothing from playing it three decades ago and the rule book was overwhelming, so I'm looking for tips on how I can jump into this and still make it a good experience for my kids.  If it takes me 5 minutes to try and figure out each step of what to do and how things work once we start, they will just get bored.

I am willing to put in the time to learn (I've been really poring over the rulebook), but I guess part of the question comes down to what parts I really need to master and what parts would it be ok if I messed up or didn't deal with. Funny enough, but the starter set rulebook says at the beginning that if you are reading this book, you should be the DM (so I would imagine that they expect that sometimes brand new groups will start D&D together and not have to get an experienced DM).

Comment: This is too broad - we don't really do "give me general tips" here.  If you are asking specifically about the "what rules you should master or not to keep play moving quickly" that's a well scoped question. Ask yourself what is the exact problem you're having (besides being worried) and what would a best answer look like?